# check if specific value exists in xml record record with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping

I have a problem where I need to check if a specific value exists in my xml. If that value exists that record shall not be mapped to the destination schema. The xml and xsd is pretty big so I will try to simplify it, and it looks something like this.

### Simplified xml:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Schema1">
 <Person>
   <Employment>
     <EmploymentPeriod>
          <lart code="0674" />
     </EmploymentPeriod>
     <EmploymentPeriod>
          <lart code="2222" />
     </EmploymentPeriod>
   </Employment>
   <Employment>
     <EmploymentPeriod>
          <lart code="0198" />
     </EmploymentPeriod>
   </Employment>
 </Person>
 <Person>
   <Employment>
     <EmploymentPeriod>
          <lart code="0133" />
     </EmploymentPeriod>
   </Employment>
  </Person>
</ns0:Root>
```

Basically a Person can contain more then one employment element with multiple employment periods. I need to check if record lart and its code attribute has a  value of 0198, if thats true that person shall not be mapped to the destination schema.

```
    <xsl:if test="ns0:Employment/ns0:EmploymentPeriod/ns0:lart[@code=0198]">
```

Removes most of the persons but some passes through. I have tried many different ways but xslt isn´t my strong side.

Could it be that the xslt code only checks the value in the first Employment record?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to show us 2 things: (a) a simplified but complete XSLT stylesheet that can replicate the issue; (b) a sample XML containing an entry that the XSLT ***fails*** to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is precisely what you are looking for, but may give you a general idea. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">


<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Person[descendant::lart[@code=0198]]">
    <xsl:comment>Do not map person with lart/@code = 0198</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Schema1">
    <!--Do not map person with lart/@code = 0198-->
    <Person>
        <Employment>
            <EmploymentPeriod>
                <lart code="0133"/>
            </EmploymentPeriod>
        </Employment>
    </Person>
</ns0:Root>
```

according to your description, it sounded like in a case where you have a  Person node with multiple Employment/EmploymentPeriods, the entire Person node was to be suppressed.

Not sure what you meant by "not mapped", in this limited example I took it to mean being omitted in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried this solution but it gives me the same result as before. I tried to count the lart node with code attribute value of 0198 to see if they where found, and yes they are counted but the person is not omitted.